# Restoring clonezilla image to newly created LVM partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, backup, lvm

I have read an article about LVM and I would like to install it. Is it possible to make first an image of my total installation, then delete everything, create new LVM partitions as explained in the Wiki and after all that, restore the image to one of the newly created LVM partitions?

I have ubuntu 14.04 64bit with all the latest updates and various development utils which would cost me days to reinstall freshly, especially as I am living in an exotic country with varying internet speeds, politely said.

Thanks for an advice

Comment: Mmmmh, I'd be interested in an *informed* answer as well, so upvoted your question, but alas, cannot help you! :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no one seems to be answering anything, I'll chuck in: No experience with LVM under Ubuntu, but experience on other OSes...

1. I would use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to clone and I would clone partitions, not the entire system, using partition-to-image.

   *Why?* Full system clone will clone the GPT or MBR as well and restoring that on top of the LVM system will surely break it
2. *Before cloning:* edit your `fstab` and get off UID and back to device paths

   *Why?* when moving disks around on one system or between systems, UID is the clear winner as nothing needs to be adapted.  In your case, you're going to rebuild the entire system, so using UID will only complicate matters, thus has no benefits.
3. Install a minimal OS as similar to the existing one as possible once LVMs have been defined.

   *Why?* 
   You can clone that too to go back to (I *would* take an entire system-to-image now!)

   You will see the relative paths and UIDs of your LVM system and restoring the images will become easier.
4. Keep the Ubuntu Boot CD handy, because you *will* have to edit the fstab of the system after restoring the partition clone.